# C++: Efficiently get Sha256 digest into OpenSSL Bignum?

Tags: c++, windows, openssl, cryptography, blockchain

**Problem**

So I'm using C++ with the OpenSSL library to try to implement my own blockchain from scratch and everything was going very well until I stumbled into a problem:

How can I store my 256bit hash digests?

At first I tried implementing my own 256-bit type out of uint8_t's

but then I gave up and decided to use OpenSSL' bignums.

But here's the thing, as far as I know, OpenSSL bignums are meant to be used for public key cryptographic functions, how can I perform hash functions such as sha256 and store the digest in a BigNum?

Or is there an alternative option that is efficient for the storage of 256-bit or more values?

Here's the code I was using before the bignums:

```
UINT<SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH> Crypto::Sha256 (const std::string &p_Data)
{
    UINT<SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH> result;
    SHA256_CTX context;

    SHA256_Init (&context);
    SHA256_Update (&context, p_Data.c_str (), p_Data.length ());
    SHA256_Final (result.m_Bytes, &context);

    return result;
}
```

Here's my own BigNum sort of implementation: (Not very efficient)

```
template<size_t BLOCK_SIZE>
struct UINT
{
    size_t blockSize = BLOCK_SIZE;
    uint8_t m_Bytes[BLOCK_SIZE];

    static UINT<BLOCK_SIZE> Zero ()
    {
        UINT<BLOCK_SIZE> r;

        for ( uint8_t &byte : r.m_Bytes )
            byte = 0b0000'0000;

        return r;
    }

    static UINT<BLOCK_SIZE> One ()
    {
        UINT<BLOCK_SIZE> r;

        for ( uint8_t &byte : r.m_Bytes )
            byte = 0b1111'1111;

        return r;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& p_OS, const UINT<BLOCK_SIZE>& p_Value)
    {
        for ( const uint8_t &byte : p_Value.m_Bytes )
            p_OS << (int) byte;

        return p_OS;
    }

    std::string Str ()
    {
        std::stringstream ss;

        for ( const uint8_t &byte : m_Bytes )
            ss << (int) byte;

        return ss.str();
    }

    bool operator==(const UINT<BLOCK_SIZE> &p_Other) const
    {
        bool r = true;

        for ( int i = 0; i < 256; ++i )
        {
            const bool X = (m_Bytes[i / 8] >> (i % 8)) & 1;
            const bool Y = (p_Other.m_Bytes[i / 8] >> (i % 8)) & 1;

            r &= ~(X ^ Y);
        }

        return r;
    }

    bool operator!=(const UINT<BLOCK_SIZE> &p_Other) const
    {
        bool r = true;

        for ( int i = 0; i < 256; ++i )
        {
            const bool X = (m_Bytes[i / 8] >> (i % 8)) & 1;
            const bool Y = (p_Other.m_Bytes[i / 8] >> (i % 8)) & 1;

            r &= X ^ Y;
        }

        return r;
    }

    bool operator>(const UINT<BLOCK_SIZE> &p_Other) const
    {
        bool r = true;

        for ( int i = 0; i < 256; ++i )
        {
            const bool X = (m_Bytes[i / 8] >> (i % 8)) & 1;
            const bool Y = (p_Other.m_Bytes[i / 8] >> (i % 8)) & 1;

            r &= X & ~Y;
        }

        return r;
    }

    bool operator<(const UINT<BLOCK_SIZE> &p_Other) const
    {
        bool r = true;

        for ( int i = 0; i < 256; ++i )
        {
            const bool X = (m_Bytes[i / 8] >> (i % 8)) & 1;
            const bool Y = (p_Other.m_Bytes[i / 8] >> (i % 8)) & 1;

            r &= ~X & Y;
        }

        return r;
    }

    bool operator>=(const UINT<BLOCK_SIZE> &p_Other) const
    {
        bool r = true;

        for ( int i = 0; i < 256; ++i )
        {
            const bool X = (m_Bytes[i / 8] >> (i % 8)) & 1;
            const bool Y = (p_Other.m_Bytes[i / 8] >> (i % 8)) & 1;

            r &= (X & ~Y) | ~(X ^ Y);
        }

        return r;
    }

    bool operator<=(const UINT<BLOCK_SIZE> &p_Other) const
    {
        bool r = true;

        for ( int i = 0; i < 256; ++i )
        {
            const bool X = (m_Bytes[i / 8] >> (i % 8)) & 1;
            const bool Y = (p_Other.m_Bytes[i / 8] >> (i % 8)) & 1;

            r &= (~X & Y) | ~(X ^ Y);
        }

        return r;
    }
};
```

**Also important to note:** 
Originally I did implement my own Sha256 function but using that would be a bad idea. Firstly I'm not an expert in cryptography, secondly, in terms of scalability it's very bad because I would have had to implement every other cryptographic function from scratch too, so I ended up choosing to use OpenSSL's ready-to-use hash functions.

**Solutions I thought about**
I thought about setting each bit within a newly created BigNum using
BN_set_bit(), however, that would not be very efficient to do since we're already putting the digest in a uint8_t array. We would be copying results twice which is kind of a dumb solution.

**Now I need either of two things:**

- To store the digest from Sha256_final or EVP_DigestFinal_ex in a bignum
- To use a different data structure to store that information.

And I need to be able to perform Arithmetic, at least 256-bit division & Greater-Equal comparison.

***Please help me!!***

Comment: Why not fork the Bitcoin and Ethereum code bases and learn from how they're implemented first? See https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin and https://github.com/ethereum/aleth for more info.

Comment: Thanks but I have already gone through the source code a little. They implemented their own Cryptographic functions, as well as big numbers. I don't want to reinvent the wheel, that's why I'm using OpenSSL. Also, this is more about using the OpenSSL library than blockchains in general.

Comment: In C++, I'd just use a `std::array<std::uint8_t, 32>` or `std::vector<std::uint8_t>` if storing the raw hash, or as a base-16 encoded string if you want something human readable.

Comment: @Shawn That's not enough because I need to perform arithmetic on the hashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I ended up using BN_bin2bn() to convert a uint8_t into a BigNum.

```
#include <openssl/bn.h>

void Crypto::Sha256 (const std::string &p_Data, BIGNUM* hash)
{
    uint8_t digestBuffer[256];
    SHA256_CTX context;

    SHA256_Init (&context);
    SHA256_Update (&context, p_Data.c_str (), p_Data.length ());
    SHA256_Final (digestBuffer, &context);

    BN_bin2bn (digestBuffer, 256, hash);
}
```